# Can't access bluetooth speaker from the www-data user

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'm trying to launch audio files on a bluetooth speaker from a web server hosted on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I'm using PulseAudio with the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` module.

I can play music on the bluetooth speaker from the `pi` account, but I didn't succeed to make it work with the `www-data` user account (the account used by the web server).

This is what I see when I list PulseAudio devices from the both accounts:

[image]
*(the bluetooth device is visible from the pi account but not for from the www-data account)*

When digging into the problem, I found that some modules are loaded for `pi`, but not for the `www-data` account.

[image]

I tried to load them manually, but I get this error:

```
raspberrypi pulseaudio[384]: E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Module "module-bluez5-discover" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
raspberrypi pulseaudio[384]: E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-bluetooth-discover" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
```

Which makes sens, because the module is already loaded for the pi account.

I don't understand how the loaded modules can be different, since there is only one instance of the PulseAudio service running on the system, right ?

Anyway, maybe this difference on the modules has nothing to do with my problem, but I find it useful to mention it.

---

The service config look like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio Daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --realtime --disallow-exit --no-cpu-limit
```

---

What I did to try to fix the problem:

- I added `www-data` in the following groups: `audio`, `bluetooth`, `pulse`, and `pulse-access`
- I defined a `$HOME` folder for `www-data` and I copied the `/home/pi/.config/pulse` folder to the `www-data` `$HOME` folder.

Do you have any idea to make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you kill the PID of the pi account, then try to access from www-data?

Comment: I have 2 process running: `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --realtime --disallow-exit --no-cpu-limit` on `pulse` user, and `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no` on `pi` user, I presume you're speaking about the second one ? I tried to kill it, but it automatically restarts, before I can do the test

Comment: Can you describe more of your setup? What software are you using to play the audio? Rather than trying to make the `www-data` user be able to play sound, why not pass the command(s) over to the `pi` user?

The only cases I can think of where that wouldn't fit is e.g. live stream uploading to the webserver, and wanting it to play that stream, but you mentioned files.

Comment: @robbat2 Right now I'm using `mplayer`, but I also tried with `aplay` before, I got the same results. It seems that the issue is on pulse/bluetooth side, not on the player side. I already tried to launch the player as "pi" from www-data. It tried using `sudo`, `sudo -u pi` or `sudo runuser -l pi`, but I always get the error "Unable to connect: Connection refused" (same when launching the command `pactl list cards short` with `sudo`/`runuser` from `www-data`)

Comment: @PaulDS You said in the original post that it worked under the `pi` user.

So you should look at what's different in that configuration where it worked, vs when you use `sudo`/`runuser` to the `pi` user.

e.g. if it only you when did an graphical interactive login to the `pi` user, then the missing setup was maybe done by something in `xinitrc` (`/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc*` or per-user).

Maybe start from basics, with what distribution & PulseAudio version you're using.

Comment: Haven't read all the comments. But 1) The modules are probably because your X-session spawns a bunch of applications that trigger module loading. Your www-data session doesn't spawn a bunch of random apps that does this. 2) Does this help at all: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/cd9ani/pulseaudio_for_multiple_users/

Comment: Is user `www-data` in the audio group?

Comment: @robbat2 I tried in SSH with the pi user, and that's strange, I can't see my device when using `pactl list cards short`, but I can play audio file on the device using mplayer. I'm using Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with PulseAudio 12.2

Comment: @Torxed I tried the method shared in the reddit thread, and it worked ! Thanks

Comment: @Torxed could you write an answer so I can give you the bounty ?

Comment: @PaulDS Done :) I copied some from your own answer, but added some additional details/rephrasing. Mainly a little warning about `/tmp` being world writeable, which may be undesirable. But should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I presume is that both users is trying to take control of the sound card/sound driver. This is because the default PulseAudio service simply tries to create a master daemon.

As per my previous comment, Arch Linux wiki has a good article on [Allowing multiple users to use PulseAudio at the same time](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Allowing_multiple_users_to_use_PulseAudio_at_the_same_time).

The goal of the above example is to have one user create the main daemon, which the other PA users connect to, thus sharing one master session. Look at it this way, you have one person owning a music studio with speakers - and others rent it to play music through those speakers. But someone has to control the setup. PA can handle quite a lot of clients and it can also be TCP/UDP based and act as a Sonos setup across multiple Raspberry Pi's ;)

To solve this multi-tenant problem, create a pulse configuration for the `pi` user: *(Skip if you already have a `default.pa` in `~/.config/pulse/`)*

```
sudo cp /etc/pulse/default.pa  ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
sudo chown pi:pi ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

Modify the `pi` pulse `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` config by adding the following to the bottom of the configuration:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/pulse-socket
```

In the `www-data` home directory, create/edit `~/.config/pulse/client.conf` and add the following:

```
default-server = unix:/tmp/pulse-socket
```

This will instruct `pi` to create a PulseAudio socket on `/tmp/pulse-socket`, and in turn tells `www-data` to connect to this socket instead of spawning a new one.

Be wary that the socket needs to be accessible by both users, and in your case it's under `/tmp` which is usually world-writable. This may be to much, in which case move the socket some where only the two users have access.